# React Redux -> Map is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-persist

So I am learning how to use redux and redux persist and currently I stuck at a problem right now. Whenever I try to map my store's content, it throws an error saying `TypeError: tasks.map is not a function` and I don't really know why the problem is occuring. I've googled around and tried debugging it, also tried to re-write the code a couple of time but it was all to no avail. Here's my entire code:
rootReducer.js

```
import React from 'react'

let nextToDo = 0;
const task=[
    {
    }
]
const reducer =(state=task, action)=>
{
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'add':
            return[
                ...state,
                {
                    name: 'new',
                    id: nextToDo+=1
                }
            ]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}


export default reducer
```

store.js

```
import reducer from './rootReducer'
import {applyMiddleware,createStore} from 'redux'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import {persistStore, persistReducer} from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

const persistConfig ={
    key: 'root',
    storage
}
export const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer)
export const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(logger));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default {store, persistor}
```

Index.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import reducer from './rootReducer'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {store} from './store'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class Index extends Component {
    render(){
    const {tasks} = this.props
    const add=()=>
    {
        store.dispatch(
            {
                type: 'add', 
            }
        )
    }
    store.subscribe(()=>console.log('your store is now', store.getState()))
    return (
        <div>
            {tasks.map(task=><div>{task.name}</div>)}
            <Button onClick={()=>add()}></Button> 
        </div>
    )
}
}
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>
{
    return{
        tasks: state
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Index)
```

Comment: Have you tried simply console.logging `tasks` before you render it?

Comment: Yes and it is exactly the object I want it to be, here it is:
`{0: {…}, count: 1, name: "new", _persist: {…}}`

Comment: @Python_Mython79 `{0: {…}, count: 1, name: "new", _persist: {…}}` is not even valid javascript syntax and unclear what it is. Can you log `JSON.stringify(state)` in mapStateToProps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare state this way:

```js
state = {
  tasks: [{}]
}
```

Then, on Index.js, you can pass it to props by doing this:

```js
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>
{
    return {
        tasks: state.tasks
    }
}
```

And use it inside the Component with `props.tasks`

Comment: well when I do it like that i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined but it clearly isn't, since I've logged tasks earlier in the code and it is not undefined

Comment: try to determine if your state is indeed changes

Comment: Yes, You're correct ! I had to change the reducer a tiny bit by changing the state in there as well, thank you very much!